# Fetched values from MIN(CAST(.. AS DATETIME)) output to php error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, pdo

I have this little problem of fetching the results via a PDO query:

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT MIN( CAST( Tstart AS DATETIME ) ) , MAX( CAST( Tend AS DATETIME ) ) , FROM TimeBase
WHERE Daynr = '131'");
$result->execute();
$keep = $result->fetch();

echo $keep['Tstart'];
echo $keep['Tend'];
```

Produces errors:

> Undefined index: Tstart
>   Undefined index: Tend

The Mysql syntax itself returns a result when I run it directly.
And the PDO was not causing any problems without the `MIN(CAST(.. AS DATETIME))` so I'm sure the problem has to do something with this syntax, but I can't find the correct way of fetching it to a php variable (or echo in this example).

So my question is what is the correct way of apprehending the fetched row as a PHP variable in this case?

From there will I be able to use this code to format it as time from a datetime row?

```
$Start_Time = $keep['time(Tstart)'];
```

Comment: Which data  type is Tstart ?

Comment: Your SQL isn't setting an alias for Tstart or Tend columns. You're running aggregate functions on those columns, so they're being returned with no name

Comment: Did you `var_dump($keep)` and see what it contains? My guess is you probably have to give column aliases to your select statement.

Comment: Thank you for the var_dump. I wasn't aware of such technology... It will be very useful also in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either treat the result as a positional array:

```
echo $keep[0];
echo $keep[1];
```

or give your columns aliases and treat the result as an associative array:

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT MIN( CAST( Tstart AS DATETIME ) ) AS tstart, 
MAX( CAST( Tend AS DATETIME ) ) AS tend
FROM TimeBase
WHERE Daynr = '131'");
$result->execute();
$keep = $result->fetch();

echo $keep['tstart'];
echo $keep['tend'];
```

Note, BTW, that you have a redundant comma before your `from` clause.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much for explaining this so good :)

Answer (score 0):

could be  you need proper alias for this

```
  SELECT MIN( CAST( Tstart AS DATETIME ) ) as t1 , 
  MAX( CAST( Tend AS DATETIME ) )  as t2, 
  FROM TimeBase
  WHERE Daynr = '131'"


 echo $keep['t1'];
 echo $keep['t2'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you SQL:

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT MIN( CAST( Tstart AS DATETIME ) ) as Tstart , 
           MAX( CAST( Tend AS DATETIME ) ) as Tend FROM TimeBase
           WHERE Daynr = '131'");
$result->execute();
```

The columns were being returned with no names, hence you couldn't reference them by name.